# loop through nested NSDictionary in plist using swift

Tags: swift, cgrect

I want to draw something using saved plist

[image: this is the plist structure]

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("draw_array", ofType: "plist");
    var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!);

    var lastPoint: CGPoint!;

    for (myKey,myValue) in dict {

        var row = myValue as NSDictionary;
        for (index, (key, value)) in enumerate(row) {
            lastPoint = CGPoint(x: dict[1]!["start"]["x"] as Int?, y: dict[1]!["start"]["y"] as Int?);
            println("index: \(index) key: \(key) value: \(value)")
        }


    }
```

I cant get the individual x and y values, and keep geting errors

Comment: What errors? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying' in dict[1]!["start"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print specific item:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("draw_array", ofType: "plist");
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!) as [String: [String: [String: AnyObject]]];
println(dict["1"]!["start"]!["x"]!)
```

Or loop to print

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "plist");
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)

for (myKey, myValue) in dict {
    for (key, value) in myValue as NSDictionary {
        let x = value["x"] as NSNumber
        let y = value["y"] as NSNumber
        // lastPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: x.integerValue, y: y.integerValue)
        println("x: \(x); y: \(y)")
    }
}
```